# How to get different results inside a react route/component and best practice for organizing them?

Tags: reactjs

Missing some basic fundamentals. This is for front-end.

I have three routes : 
/lists/all
/lists/pending
/lists/completed

They all have the same exact layout, so I want to reuse the template /lists/all is using for pending and completed.

My folder structure :
src/views/lists/all.js
src/components/table.js

I can have 2 additional view js files pending.js and completed.js that just calls the same table component with different data.

Is there a way to make all.js check which route it's on and conditionally load the table component with different data? or is it best practice to separate them into separate view files since they show different data?

Is maybe there some sort of method I can call inside componentDidLoad() and a way to check the current route url? and I can fetch the correct ajax request based on that logic? Thinking $match.route == '/lists/all' else if $match.route == 'lists/pending' sorta thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, I'm assuming that all three of these listing have the same API structure and you would conditionally be able to load data for all three.

Since we have three routes at hand, we can start with building out these routes:

```
<Route path={`/listing/:type(all|pending|completed)`} component={List}>
```

We use a param `:type` so we can identify which route user has gone to, but constrain with regular expression that params should be one of `all`, `pending` or `completed`.

Now inside the `List` component:

```
class List extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { match } = this.props;
    const { type } = match.params;

    // Do what you want with type here. type: 'all' | 'pending' | 'completed'
  }
  render() {
    return (
      // render tables
    );
  }
}
```